# Grouping columns and calc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have my code as below:

```
df.loc[df['Shape'].isin(Shapes), 'Shape'].value_counts().div(len(df)).to_frame().reset_index()
```

This gives me the number of occurrences and then % where that value is lets say a triangle for the entire dataframe. But if I want to add another column to layer it as a group by how would I tweak this?

Current Code gives me the % of each shape in the entire df

```
Triangle .20
Square   .40
Circle   .40
```

I also want it with color so output would be below:

```
Triangle  Blue  .20
Triangle  Red   .40
Triangle  Black .40
Square    Blue  .40
Square    Red   .30
Square    Purple.30
...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with multiple columns:

```
np.random.seed(2020)
s = ['Triangle','Square','Circle', 'Rectangle']
c = ['Blue','Red','Black', 'Purple']    

df = pd.DataFrame({'Shape':np.random.choice(s, size=20),
                   'Colors':np.random.choice(c, size=20)})
#print (df)

Shapes = ['Triangle','Square','Circle'] 

df1 = (df.loc[df['Shape'].isin(Shapes)]
           .groupby(['Shape', 'Colors'])
           .size()
           .div(len(df))
           .reset_index(name='per'))
print (df1)
      Shape  Colors   per
0    Circle   Black  0.10
1    Circle     Red  0.05
2    Square    Blue  0.05
3    Square     Red  0.10
4  Triangle   Black  0.05
5  Triangle    Blue  0.05
6  Triangle  Purple  0.10
7  Triangle     Red  0.10
```

Alternative with [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html), difference is values are sorted per groups:

```
df1 = (df.loc[df['Shape'].isin(Shapes)]
           .groupby(['Shape'])['Colors']
           .value_counts()
           .div(len(df))
           .reset_index(name='per'))
print (df1)
      Shape  Colors   per
0    Circle   Black  0.10
1    Circle     Red  0.05
2    Square     Red  0.10
3    Square    Blue  0.05
4  Triangle  Purple  0.10
5  Triangle     Red  0.10
6  Triangle   Black  0.05
7  Triangle    Blue  0.05
```

If want percentages per groups (sum percentage of each group is `1` or `100%`) then use:

```
Shapes = ['Triangle','Square','Circle'] 

df2 = (df.loc[df['Shape'].isin(Shapes)]
           .groupby(['Shape'])['Colors']
           .value_counts(normalize=True)
           .reset_index(name='per'))
print (df2)
      Shape  Colors       per
0    Circle   Black  0.666667
1    Circle     Red  0.333333
2    Square     Red  0.666667
3    Square    Blue  0.333333
4  Triangle  Purple  0.333333
5  Triangle     Red  0.333333
6  Triangle   Black  0.166667
7  Triangle    Blue  0.166667
```

Comment: Thanks, why from value_counts() to size()?

Comment: the only thing above does not do is calc the percentage for each grouped by properly, meaning each shape and colors per has to total 100% because they should add up to 100 for each segment, I think it takes the total % of the entire df

Comment: @Chris90 - so you need `df1 = (df.loc[df['Shape'].isin(Shapes)]
           .groupby(['Shape'])['Colors']
           .value_counts(normalize=True)
           .reset_index(name='per'))` ?